CDK LambdaRestAPI without root path methods
I'm trying to create a LambdaRestApi via CDK following along with this workshop.
// Define aws lambda resource
const helloLambda = new Function(this, 'HelloHandler', {
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  code: Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'hello.handler'
});

// Define an API GW Rest API
const api = new LambdaRestApi(this, 'Endpoint', {
  handler: helloLambda,
  deployOptions: {
    stageName: 'development'
  }
});

However, this creates an API Gateway that looks like the following:

When I've done this in the past without CDK, I've always created resources without any methods on the top level root '/' path like so:

Is there a way to achieve this via the CDK LambdaRestApi? I've played around with the options, including setting proxy: false and adding the proxy integration manually to a RestApi rather than a LambdaRestApi. It's not clear to me why if you're using a proxy you'd want the methods on the top level path.
I've tried adding the proxy directly and see that the root path methods are still created.
// Define aws lambda resource
const helloLambda = new Function(this, 'HelloHandler', {
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  code: Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'hello.handler'
});

// Define an API GW Rest API
const api = new RestApi(this, 'Endpoint', {
  deployOptions: {
    stageName: 'development'
  }
});
api.root.addProxy({ defaultIntegration: new LambdaIntegration(helloLambda) });


I wonder if the anyMethod property does what you're asking?
api.root.addProxy({ 
  anyMethod: false, 
  defaultIntegration: new LambdaIntegration(helloLambda) 
});

